# Entity Framework. Несколько связей многие ко многим между двумя таблицами

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Используется `Code First`.

Есть модели `Product`и `User`. Пользователь может иметь много продуктов купленных онлайн и много купленных оффлайн. В то же время у продукта есть список пользователей, которые приобрели онлайн и список оффлайн соответственно.

Получается мы имеем 2 связи многие ко многим. Как реализовать это в классах моделей?

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> OnlineCustomers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> OfflineCustomers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> OnlinePurchases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> OfflinePurchases { get; set; }
}
```

Насколько знаю, при связи многие ко многим EF автоматически создает третью таблицу, именуя ее `ProductUsers`. Но если связи две, как будут именоваться дополнительные таблицы? И как можно изменить правило именования промежуточных таблиц, каким атрибутом или Fluent API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fluent API**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(q => q.OnlineCustomers)
                .WithMany(q => q.OnlinePurchases)
                .Map(q =>
                {
                    q.ToTable("OnlineProductUsers");
                    q.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
                    q.MapRightKey("UserId");
                });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(q => q.OfflineCustomers)
                .WithMany(q => q.OfflinePurchases)
                .Map(q =>
                {
                    q.ToTable("OfflineProductUsers");
                    q.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
                    q.MapRightKey("UserId");
                });
}
```

Всего будет 4 таблицы: `Product, User, OnlineProductUsers, OfflineProductUsers`

**Data Annotations**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("OnlinePurchases")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> OnlineCustomers { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("OfflinePurchases")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> OfflineCustomers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> OnlinePurchases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> OfflinePurchases { get; set; }
}
```

Недостаток в том, что EF сам придумает названия новым таблицам

Всего будет 4 таблицы: `Product, User, ProductUsers, ProductUser1`

Comment: При этом указанные в вопросе классы моделей остаются как есть? Ничего изменять не нужно?

Comment: если используете Fluent API классы моделей остаются как есть. Если хотите использовать аннотации данных можно использовать атрибут `InverseProperty`

Comment: Понял, спасибо!